# Opening a php file with xampp

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I'm very new to web development and I'm trying to create a php contact form. I'm trying to launch it on a xampp development server, but I can't seem to figure out how. according to [this site,](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-run-a-php-file-in-xampp) I need to type localhost then some options of files should show up. Well it doesn't, the xampp dashboard just shows up, and my files are in the htdocs folder. Am I opening them wrong or whats happening, I've been stuck on this for hours?

Comment: Is apache service running ? What are you seeing when access to http://localhost in browser ?

Comment: i would go to the source documentation: https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html

Comment: @ramiromd Ya it is, when i access localhost I see the dashboard for xampp, a welcome page "Welcome to XAMPP for Windows 7.1.10" then a bunch more text. I tried just running it from netbeans but i get a message saying object not found!..etc

Comment: What is the filename ? If you file is located in htdodcs/myfile.php then you can access it as http://localhost/myfile.php

Comment: It simply means that xampp's default index page is still there. You need to rename or delete it and put your own.

Comment: index.php is the filename

Comment: @icecub how do I do that?

Comment: Depending on where you installed xampp, there should be a `htdocs` folder. In that folder will be some index.html or index.php file. That's the default file you need to replace

Answer (score 24):

First you need to start XAMPP. So, go to the drive where you install the XAMPP server. Generally, it's installed in `C` drive. So, go to `C:\xampp\` . And open the file `xampp-control.exe` . When the controller open you need to start the `Apache` and `Mysql` . Then you see the green color besides `Apache` and `Mysql` . It means they are running or started. OK. 
Now, go to `C:\xampp\htdocs` and create a folder as you want. For an example you can create folder which name is `hello` . Then open this folder and create a file which name is `index.php` and open it  in you editor write a basic code like this:

`<?php 
 echo "Hello World";
?>`

Then save it. And open your browser. And go to `localhost/hello`

`hello` means the folder name you created.
Now, you will see the output. Which showing `Hello World`

Feel free to asking any question. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 4):

make sure your apache service on your XAMPP is running, if you using database, activate mysql too.

and save your file in `C:\xampp\htdocs`

if your file index.php, you can access it as `localhost/index.php`

if you make folder inside htdocs like `C:\xampp\htdocs\test`

you can access it as `localhost/test/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

first check xampp is installed or not.
check the **Apache** service is started or not.
save your `filename.php` file in `"xampp/htdocs/**filename.php**"`
Access your php file. `localhost/filename.php`
If your php file is in folder than : `localhost/foldername/filename.php`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you don't have a file have the name "index" under htdocs folder. Then :

1. Lanch **xampp-control.exe** ( you will find it under XAMPP folder )
2. **Start** Apache and MySql
3. Open the browser **in private** (incognito).
4. Write as URL : **localhost**.

Done! You will find all files that exists on htdocs folder.

Note : I proposed to use incognito to avoid cookies problem.

XAMPP open files named index as default files ( You can change that setting ) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

1. Delete 'index.php'
   or
2. Edit 'index.php' so it runs your code on startup

for option 2 you need to find "C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php" and:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/myCode.html');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

I hope this helps, this is my first comment on a question, i believe the initial code is:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/index.html');
    exit;
    Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This maybe works.

Go to "http://localhost/xampp/".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31878181)